# How to setup Nginx as a load balancer using the StrongLoop Nginx Controller

Tags: nginx, amazon-ec2, loopbackjs, strongloop

I'm attempting to setup Nginx as a load balancer using the StrongLoop Nginx Controller. Nginx will be acting as a load balancer for a StrongLoop LoopBack application hosted by the standalone StrongLoop Process Manager. However, I've been unsuccessful at making the Nginx deployment following [the official directions](http://docs.strongloop.com/display/SLC/Configuring+Nginx+load+balancer) from StrongLoop. Here are the steps I've taken:

**Step #1** -- My first step was to install Nginx and the StrongLoop Nginx Controller on an AWS EC2 instance. I launched an EC2 sever (Ubuntu 14.04) to host the load balancer, and attached an Elastic IP to the server. Then I executed the following commands:

```
$ ssh -i ~/mykey.pem ubuntu@[nginx-ec2-ip-address]
$ sudo apt-get update
$ sudo apt-get install nginx
$ sudo apt-get install build-essential
$ curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_0.12 | sudo bash -
$ sudo apt-get install -y nodejs
$ sudo npm install -g strong-nginx-controller 
$ sudo sl-nginx-ctl-install -c 444
```

Then I opened up port 444 in the security group of the EC2 instance using a Custom TCP Rule.

**Step #2** -- My second step was to setup two Loopback application servers. To accomplish this I launched two more EC2 servers (both Ubuntu 14.04) for the application servers, and attached an Elastic IP to each server. Then I ran the following series of commands, once on each application server:

```
$ ssh -i ~/mykey.pem ubuntu@[application-server-ec2-ip-address]
$ sudo apt-get update
$ sudo apt-get install build-essential
$ curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_0.12 | sudo bash -
$ sudo apt-get install -y nodejs
$ sudo npm install -g strong-pm
$ sudo sl-pm-install
$ sudo /sbin/initctl start strong-pm
```

**Step #3** -- My third step was to deploy the application to each of the application servers. For this I used StrongLoop Arc:

```
$ cd /path/to/loopback-getting-started-intermediate # my application
$ slc arc
```

Once in the StrongLoop Arc web console, I built a tar for the application, and deployed it to both application servers. Then in the Arc Process Manager, I connected to both application servers. Once connected, I clicked "load balancer," and entered the Nginx host and port into the form and pressed save. This caused a message to pop up saying "load balancer config saved."

*Something strange happened at this point:* The fields in StrongLoop Arc where I just typed the settings for the load balancer (host and port) reverted back to the original values the fields had before I started typing. (The original port value was 555 and the original value in the host field was the address of my second application server.)

**Don't know what to do next** -- This is where I really don't know what to do next. (I tried opening my web browser and navigating to the IP address of the Nginx load balancer, using several different port values. I tried 80, 8080, 3001, and 80, having opened up each in the security group, in an attempt to find the place to which I need to navigate in order to see "load balancing" in action. However, I saw nothing by navigating to each of these places, with the exception of port 80 which served up the "welcome to Nginx page," not what I'm looking for.)

How do I setup Nginx as a load balancer using the StrongLoop Nginx Controller? What's the next step in the process, assuming all of my steps listed are correct.

Comment: This is being discussed in detail on the forums https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/loopbackjs/ZKA6xDJYPJg

Answer (score 0):

What I usually do is this:

```
sudo sl-nginx-ctl-install -c http://0.0.0.0:444
```

Maybe this can solve your problem.